# How to read RFID using iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, xcode4, rfid

In My application i need to read the RFIDs. How it will be possible. I dont have any idea how to achieve this. Is there any API for this.Please suggest me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here is the same question but for iOS 8.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to buy an rfid reader for iPhone, and use its SDK.
Have a look to [iCarte](http://www.icarte.ca/), it could be a good starting point.

Comment: If we will buy the RFID reader ,  will it provide SDK for us? Regarding to How to read the RFID's and show in our own application?

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED Search Google for `rfid reader iphone sdk`: you'll see several examples of companies offering sdks for their iPhone rfid readers, including the iCarte mentioned by @netrace