# Reading RFID tag in iPhone App using NFC Reader

Tags: iphone, ios, nfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read RFID using iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429961/how-to-read-rfid-using-iphone-sdk)

I am new to this technology

I have to develop an iPhone application which will **read RFID tag using NFC reader**, but NFC reader are not in-built available in iPhone.

So my question is how can I read RFID tag data in iPhone App using NFC Reader hardware. Is there any external hardware of NFC reader and if yes, how do I program to connect that reader from my application.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any experience in using them, but they look promising: http://www.icarte.ca
But you will have to contact them if you want to get their API.